# How to handle filter with multiple parameters React

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make search filter with multiple parameters but I'm having problems. I've made states for all the inputs and I want to filter results whenever one of the input values change.
What I don't know is how to update the result so it displays properly.

```
const Products = () => {
  useEffect(async () => {
    setLoading(true);
    await axios
      .get('/articles.json')
      .then(res => {
        const allProducts = [];
        for (let key in res.data) {
          allProducts.push(res.data[key]);
        }
        setProducts(allProducts);
        setFiltered(allProducts);
        setLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  }, []);



  return (
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <div className={classes.Center}>
        <div className={classes.Heading}>
          <h1>Our Products</h1>
          <span className={classes.Subtitle}>Search and buy</span>
        </div>
        <Filters
        />
        <div className={classes.SingleContainer}>
          {filtered ? filtered : <Spinner />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

[Here is how frontend looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IicQB.png)

Answer (score 0):

I'd make your filtered data a variable using `useMemo` or have the logic in a separate `useEffect` based on your products state and filter input values.

You will definitely need to set up whatever callbacks you need to get the filter inputs out of `Filters` (where I assume they are)

As a note, you shouldn't have the `useEffect` function be async on it's own. Set up an inner function which will give you the ability to actually run cleanup (via a return callback)

```
const Products = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      setLoading(true);
      await axios
        .get('/articles.json')
        .then((res) => {
          const allProducts = [];
          for (let key in res.data) {
            allProducts.push(res.data[key]);
          }
          setProducts(allProducts);
          setLoading(false);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          console.log(err);
        });
      fetchData();
    };
  }, []);
  const filtered = useMemo(() => {
    if (!products) return products;
    return products.filter(() => {
      // Some calculations based on the inputs
    });
  }, [products, search, category, price, rating, deal]);

  return (
    <div className={classes.Container}>
      <div className={classes.Center}>
        <div className={classes.Heading}>
          <h1>Our Products</h1>
          <span className={classes.Subtitle}>Search and buy</span>
        </div>
        <Filters
        // Relevant callbacks to be able to set the filter states that we care about for the filtered
        />
        <div className={classes.SingleContainer}>
          {filtered ? filtered : <Spinner />}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```